# Completely hide the :PROPERTIES: drawer in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

**Prelude:** [Stackoverflow post: Completely hide the :PROPERTIES: drawer in org-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478260/completely-hide-the-properties-drawer-in-org-mode)

The above post already has an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17492723/4949315). This question is a follow up to that. I started discussion in the comment section of the above post seeking more help. However, as suggested by the OP of the answer:

1. that "it sounds like [I] need more assistance than can be provided in comments", and
2. that "answer was written in 2017 (approximately 5 years ago), and it is entirely possible that the code of `org-cycle-internal-local` has changed", and
3. that "It may behoove [me] to launch a new question on emacs.stackexchange.com" so that "[I] can receive dedicated attention to [my] particular use-case, taking into consideration a current version of `org-mode`"

I am posting a new question as a follow-up to the above.

**My questions:**

How exactly is the accepted answer working? No, I am not looking for a full tutorial on `elisp` (and that could not fit in the scope of a stackexchange post!). But I want answers to these particular facets of the solution:

1. In the suggested patch to `org-cycle-internal-local` there is no mention of `org-cycle-hide-drawers` function. So how are these two things talking to one-another?
2. If you `C-h k TAB` then you would notice `TAB` is bound to `org-cycle`. Well how is `org-cycle` talking with `org-cycle-internal-local`?

These answers may help me to *tinker better* in future. And learning `elisp` is probably *life long* journey. So whatever I can learn from these answers for now!

**Bonus-section: Documenting my steps:** I successfully implemented the accepted answer.

However, as I found the instructions in the accepted answer to be terse and advanced for my level of familiarity with `emacs` and `org-mode`, I am documenting here my steps for benefit of anyone else:

1. I included the `org-cycle-hide-drawers` definition from the accepted answer in my `.emacs`. Now if I relaunched `emacs` my `:PROPERTIES:` drawers don't show. Great!
2. But how do I unfold? For this I added the patch suggested to `org-cycle-internal-local` . First I did `C-h f org-cycle-internal-local` to find a link to `org.el`. From there I found the source code for `org-cycle-internal-local`. I copied that source code to my `.emacs`. In that copied code, I inserted the patch *before* `(t ;; Default action: hide the subtree. . . .` as suggested in the accepted answer. So snippet after my edit looks like this (including two lines before and two lines after the edit):

   ```
    (unless (org-before-first-heading-p)
        (run-hook-with-args 'org-cycle-hook 'subtree)))

     ;; Adding these lines from: 
     ;; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478260/completely-hide-the-properties-drawer-in-org-mode
     ((eq org-cycle-subtree-status 'subtree)
    (org-show-subtree)
    (org-unlogged-message "ALL")
    (setq org-cycle-subtree-status 'all))

     (t
    ;; Default action: hide the subtree.
    (run-hook-with-args 'org-pre-cycle-hook 'folded)
   ```
3. Now everything works beautifully! I can press `TAB` to cycle through: "1)fully folded, 2) text + children, 3) 2 + children text, 4) 3 + drawers".

Comment: On Q.2: in my version of Org mode (Org mode version 9.5.5 (release_9.5.5-776-g0432f4)) `org-cycle` is a function defined in `org-cycle.el` as you find by asking for its docstring with `C-h f org-cycle`. The filename in that description is a link that takes you to the definition of the function (in my case, that's line 268 of `org-cycle.el`). Searching forward from there for `org-cycle-internal-local` shows that `org-cycle` calls `org-cycle-internal-local` (see line 400 of the file).